# ReactJS how to add momentJS to object attribute

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

How can I add `MomentJS` to an attribute inside an object in an `ReactJS`-app?

I tried to do this but it isn't working:

```
import moment from 'moment'

class View extends React.Component {
   constructor() {
    super()

    this.state = {
       data: [
        {
            "name" : "user1",
            "created" : "2017-05-18T12:55:18.6056923"
        }
      ]
   }

}

render() {
    return(
        <p>{this.state.data.createdTs.moment().format('DDDD Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a')}</p>
    )
 }

}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`moment` takes a date object as a parameter and your data is an array, if you want only the first option use

```
render() {
    return(
        <p>{moment(this.state.data[0].createdTs).format('DDDD Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a')}</p>
    )
 }
```

else map

```
render() {
    return(
        <p>{this.state.data.map((data) => {
             return <span>{moment(data.createdTs).format('DDDD Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a')}</span>
        })}</p>
    )
 }
```

Comment: @Shubham_Khatri perfect! exactly what I wanted! Thanks alot! :-)

Comment: Glad to have helped :), Added some more info, in case you wish to map